# Partial derivitive of a summation.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation, partial-derivative

I need some help taking the partial derivative of this function, if it is possible.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Try it with an example, like with $n=3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\lambda_3x_3+,...,+\lambda_nx_n \right)$

Note that you are taking the partial derivative with respect to a specific $x_i$ and not cycling through all the values of $i$ as you do in the summation $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n$.

For example if $i=2$ you have

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \left(\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\lambda_3x_3+,...,+\lambda_nx_n \right)$

Or

$0+\lambda_2+0+0+,...+0$

(as $x_1,x_3...x_n$ are all treated as constants)

I have assumed the $\lambda_i$ are just constants and not functions of $x_i$

Comment: Great explanation, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It will be $\lambda_i$, since all others will be zeros.

Comment: Could you explain to me why wouldn't it be nλi? I was under the impression that if I take the derivative with respect to x_i inside the summation, I would be left with the sum to n of λi.    Thanks!